# Can exit-polls for European Elections be published?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, european-union, european-parliament, exit-polls

European elections are run over multiple days - the earliest voting countries in the EU are voting today, and the final votes will be on Sunday.

Is it permissible for an exit-poll for a single country (e.g. the UK) to be published before the remaining countries have voted?

I'm especially interested in UK and EU law regarding this.

Comment: By comparison, I believe that in the US, which spans time zones from UTC-4 to UTC+10, has no such rules and will happily broadcast Eastern results when Hawaii and Alaska are still voting (probably few people care about results in UTC-4 and nearly nobody about results in UTC+10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's illegal. The following is an extract from the relevant [BBC editorial guidelines](https://www.bbc.co.uk/editorialguidelines/).

> No opinion poll on any issue relating to the election may be published until after the polls have closed throughout the European Union (ie Sunday 26 May).
>
> Whilst the polls are open throughout Europe, it is a criminal offence to broadcast anything about the way in which people have voted in that election or to forecast the election result, which includes how a particular party or candidate may have fared, based on how people have voted.

Answer (score 3):

No, they may not. Which doesn't mean it doesn't happen though; it seems the Netherlands doesn't have a stellar reputation in that aspect: https://www.politico.eu/article/commission-prohibits-early-publishing-of-election-results/

AFAIK, a country may (and have done so in the past) publish turnout figures.

Comment: Netherlands also publishes European Netherlands results when Caribbean Netherlands are still voting.